# How can I pass “build-step parameters” to a downstream project (freestyle project with parameterized triggers)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins setup with two freestyle-projects linked via Jenkins upstream/downstream post-build triggers (Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin). The upstream project builds something that is uploaded somewhere. And the downstream project picks that new thing up and tests it.

At the moment the downstream project finds the build by date by looking for “the latest”. I want to change that.

**I would like to change upstream to generate a random string as filename in the build step and pass that to downstream as parameter. How can I do that?**

(I know how to generate a random string – the point is: how to pass build-step information down to the “downstream job”?)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not sure what you are asking exactly. Do you have a hard time generating a random string and use it as a filename, do you not know how to pass this random string as a downstream parameter, both ?

Comment: @Pom12: generating a random string would not be a jenkins question... The random string is actually an example: How do I pass something generated in a build-step in one job down to the “downstream” job? That is the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your upstream pipeline script, add this:

```
build job: 'your-downstream-job', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'YOUR_STRING_PARAM', value: "${yourRandomGeneratedStringVariable}" ]]
```

And your `your-downstream-job` should be e.g. a normal job which is parameterized (check the tick at *This project is parameterized*), with the *StringParameter* `YOUR_STRING_PARAM`.

Then just read the value of this environment variable and you can go on.

Comment: What is the “upstream pipeline script”? Where is that “build job:” where I should put this in? Where should I set `yourRandomGeneratedStringVariable`?

Comment: @Robert, since you say you use the build pipeline, so the upstream pipeline script is actually the your upstream job used.   About "where is that job", I guess you only have two job, upstream, downstream, so you have no choice. "Where should I put it", if you use Jenkins pipeline plugin, then you should put them into the dsl script area, for detail, you can ref this https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md, "Where should I set yourRandomGeneratedStringVariable?" I think you can set it directly inside your dsl script, or you can directly pass the dynamic variable.

Comment: @Tim, I have no DSL and no groovy. – I do have upstream and downstream jobs... Maybe I used the wrong word? Is that not a pipeline?

Comment: Pipelines is DSL, scriptable via Groovy. If you don't use Groovy at all you are not using pipelines. What did you choose when creating your job ? Did you select "Free-style project", "Maven project", ... ? We will be able to help you better once we know the type of project you have !

Comment: @Pom12, I got no trigger from your comment... I just realized that the word “pipeline” is overloaded in the Jenkins community. I don’t use that pipeline plugin, but the parameterized trigger plugin. – I edited my question.

Comment: I’m not sure how to get out of this situation: mrkernelpanic, would you delete your answer, please? :-)